# BootsFaces CommandButton does not fire action in BackingBean

Tags: jsf, commandbutton, bootsfaces

I'm currently working on a project that i want to use bootsfaces in.
The application is in a functioning state. I'm just rebuilding it for the looks.

Before, there was a richFaces navigationBar that was working just fine and i replaced it with bootstraps default navbar. So i adapted all the navigation links and labels but the only thing that is not working is the Logout-Button.

navigation.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Titel und Schalter werden für eine bessere mobile Ansicht zusammengefasst -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Navigation ein-/ausblenden</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"/>
                <span class="icon-bar"/>
                <span class="icon-bar"/>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.xhtml" style="padding: 4px;">
                <img alt="Home" src="T_Logo_3c_p.png" width="96" height="42"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Alle Navigationslinks, Formulare und anderer Inhalt werden hier zusammengefasst und können dann ein- und ausgeblendet werden -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Vehicles<span class="caret"/></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="car-overview.xhtml">Overview</a></li>
                        <li><a href="booking.xhtml">Booking</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">#{loginBean.username}<span class="caret"/></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="myInfo.xhtml">My Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="myOrders.xhtml">My Orders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="invoice.xhtml">My Invoices</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="report.xhtml">Submission</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administration<span class="caret"/></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="vehicles.xhtml">Manage Vehicles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="charges.xhtml">Manage Charges</a></li>
                        <li><a href="areas.xhtml">Manage Parking Areas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="damages.xhtml">Manage Damages</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"/>
                        <li><a href="users.xhtml">Manage Users</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <b:commandButton class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Log out" action="#{loginBean.logout}"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type=""/>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type=""/>
```

Home.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
>
<h:head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" content=""/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="T_favicon_p.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <title>Azubiprojekt CarSharing</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1 class="text-center">CarSharing</h1>

    <!-- include navBar here -->
    <ui:include src="./navigation.xhtml" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type=""/>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type=""/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And the SessionScoped LoginBeans method:

```
public String logout() {
    HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
    session.invalidate();
    return "index";
}
```

The Error when entering the page: `The class 'de.carsharing.beans.LoginBean' does not have the property 'logout'.`

If I make it `action="#{loginBean.logout()}"` , the page is loaded, but the method is not called upon button clicking.

I've read about some problems of commandButtons inside `ui:components`, so i tried to include it manually, but it didn't help. The same with placing it inside an invisible h:form.

I dont know, could it be, that the b:commandButtons "action" attribute is not evaluated as a MethodExpression, but as a ValueExpression instead?

Comment: do a view-source of the page (in the browser) See a `<b:commandButton>`? _"I dont know, could it be, that the b:commandButtons "action" attribute is not evaluated as a MethodExpression, but as a ValueExpression instead?"_ Yes fi the component is not recognized it will be

Comment: At first glance, your code seems to be OK to me. The "ValueExpression" idea crossed my mind, too, but it's unlikely. I suggest you add a breakpoint to the `CommandButtonRenderer` of BootsFaces. Is the method `decode(.)` ever called? If so, does it call the `AjaxRenderer` at line 62?

Comment: Alternatively, you could send me your project. "AzubiProject" doesn't sound like a lot of copyright hassles, but please check this first. The ideal solution is to upload a down-stripped minimal reproducer to GitHub. Before you ask: I know that's demanding a lot, but on the other hand, we're answering SO questions in our precious spare-time :).

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting those two scripts from bootstraps tutorial.
Somehow, bootsfaces doesnt need those anymore